# How to use font-lock to set other text properties (particularly keymap)?

Tags: font-lock, keymap, text-properties

I'm trying to make a mode where certain strings in the buffer have a special keymap active when the point is inside them. The documentation for `font-lock-extra-managed-props` and the Elisp info manual section `Search-based Fontification` suggest this is possible:

> However, FACESPEC can also evaluate to a list of this form:
>   (face FACE PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2...)
>   to specify the face FACE and various additional text properties to
>   put on the text that matches.  If you do this, be sure to add the
>   other text property names that you set in this way to the value of
>   ‘font-lock-extra-managed-props’ so that the properties will also be
>   cleared out when they are no longer appropriate.  Alternatively,
>   you can set the variable ‘font-lock-unfontify-region-function’ to a
>   function that clears these properties.

Unfortunately the documentation isn't very clear on the format of FACESPEC--I've tried variously quoted versions and none have the desired effect of a keymap active only in a certain area. So here's a simplified version of my code:

```
;;; Face to highlight trigger zone
(defface trigger-zone-face '((t (:foreground "gold" :background "red")))
  "Highlight a trigger zone.")
;;; Function to trigger
(defun trigger-zone-function ()
  "Function to test trigger zones."
  (interactive)
  (message "Trigger-zone activated!"))
;;; Map active in trigger zone
(defvar trigger-zone-map
  (let ((keymap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key keymap (kbd "C-c i") #'trigger-zone-function))
  "Map to activate in trigger zone.")
;;; Font locking
(setq trigger-zone-highlights
      '(("trigger-zone" face trigger-zone-face keymap trigger-zone-map)))
;;; Trigger zone mode
(define-derived-mode trigger-zone-mode text-mode "trigger"
  "Major mode to trigger commands from text."
  (setq font-lock-extra-managed-props '(keymap help-echo))
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(trigger-zone-highlights)))
```

Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I think I may be formatting the FACESPEC wrong, but I can't find any documentation to clarify e.g. what parts of the list should be quoted.

Comment: By the way: better might be `setq-local font-lock-extra-managed-props`… as opposed to plain `setq`, so it affects only `trigger-zone-mode` buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(defconst trigger-zone-highlights
          '(("trigger-zone"
             (0 '(face trigger-zone-face keymap trigger-zone-map)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to set the `keymap` property, thanks! I had to make some other changes to achieve the desired behavior:  

     `(("trigger-zone" (0 '(face trigger-zone-face keymap ,trigger-zone-keymap))))